# Maven and Eclipse: project build error dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, dependencies

I just started working with Maven, and I've ran into several issues.
The latest is that one:

> Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.github.koraktor:steamcondenser:jar is missing.

I'm running eclipse for Java Developers, with m2eclipse plugin, on Windows 7 x64.
What I'm trying to do is install this API into my project:

https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-java

I have been googling for the last hour with no success. What am I supposed to do?
I tried adding the dependency from both the eclipse plugin and the pom.xml itself, but it didn't help.

EDIT:

Thanks everyone, as you said, all I had to do was including the version in the pom.xml.

Comment: You are supposed to include the version element in the dependency element.

Comment: You need to add the `<version>` for the dependency.

Answer (score 4):

Maven needs a "version" specifier in the dependency.

I use http://mvnrepository.com a lot to get the *real* Maven code for a given project.  In this case, it's at:  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.koraktor/steam-condenser/1.2.0.

Here's their version of the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.koraktor</groupId>
    <artifactId>steam-condenser</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```